# Application to password protect specific application

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am using Windows 7. Is there any software which can password protect specific application? Must be a freeware application

Comment: What is wrong with the many applications that turn up when you google [password protect windows application](http://www.google.com/search?q=password+protect+windows+application)? If you have any specific requirements please add them to your question by clicking [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/373303/edit).

Answer (score 3):

You could password protect/encrypt the main exe file of the application, with something like [Protect Exe](http://www.paehl.de/cms/oldtools)

This may cause problems with UAC, not actually tested it

Comment: What I can tell, Protect Exe looks like it writes to the Program Files (even though it doesn't have to). This will create issues with UAC.